# Error after deleting default users in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I installed my software on client pc with SQL Server 2005, it was running correctly, until I deleted the administrator, user and nt built in accounts.

Now the software connects but can't retain the connection state.

I am getting this error. ^

> *ERROR : ExecuteReader requires an open and available connection.*

Before user deletion there was no error.

Comment: pls show us your connection string. What authentication mode is set within sqlServer 2005 (mixed, sqlserver??)

Comment: user id = ; password = ; server="+System.Environment.MachineName+"\\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection = yes; database = ; Connection timeout = 10; MultipleActiveResultSets=True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably deleted the user account the application uses to connect to the database - are you using integrated security?
Check the connection string.

Comment: Thank you very much, after changing the yes to no , it start working as required.